# Where do i have to store uploaded files in maven spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, file, maven

I upload file in my web application . But  as soon as the app is redeployed the uploaded files are also getting deleted. I stored my files in webapp/images. 
But I read that " Files should be uploaded outside of the web app location." 
Where do i have to upload the file? In disk C or D , for example?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [Spring Uploading files](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) guide.
 There is a command named `CommandLineRunner` which creates the directory for you.

> You also want a target folder to upload files to, so there is a Java
>   8 lambda used to create a Boot CommandLineRunner at startup which
>   creates that folder.

The snippet is:

```
 @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init() {
        return (String[] args) -> {
            new File(ROOT).mkdir();
        };
    }
```

Comment: I saved files: `File newFile = new File(path +fileName);`
How must be my path?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist those files regardless of your webapp, ofcourse you need to save it in a folder of your choice, but outside your app dir (on the server, or any network directory). 
You could use any Writer for that (usually BufferedWriter).

You could have a properties that specify the dir path, that way it's easy to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You must upload your uploaded data outside of your apps dir. Be aware of make backups of that data.

Comment: I uploaded in **C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.18/uploads/images/** . But then I can't get images in my jsp , get error  **Not allowed to load local resource**

Comment: How do you load them?

Comment: `MultipartFile file = uploadedFile.getFile();
        String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
        String path ="C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.18/uploads/images/";
            inputStream = file.getInputStream();
            File newFile = new File(path +fileName);                  newFile.createNewFile();`

Comment: I don't know what path I must write